# Fish shell not showing branch name

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, fish

here's my problem
[image]

i install fishshell and made some changes in the config and i'm geting question marks instead of branch name..
any hints??

```
#config.fish

if status is-interactive

set -g theme_svn_prompt_enabled yes
set -g scm_prompt_blacklist "/path/to/blacklist"
set -gx VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT 1

end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We would need your fish version and the name of whatever theme you are using, but honestly you should probably just open a bug with your theme. The authors are much more likely to be able to help you.